# Creating robot models in stage under ROS‏

Tags: ros, simulation, stageros, stage, create

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have found a tutorial, which describes how to create robot models for player/stage. Can I apply this 1:1 to stageros? In particular does the stage wrapper in ros support all sensors? Or are there any limitations?

BR

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/44792/creating-robot-models-in-stage-under-ros%E2%80%8F/) by [Eisenhorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3282/eisenhorn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 82 on 2012-09-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) on 2012-10-01**:
Which tutorial did you find? It's difficult to answer your question about the 1:1 applicability if you don't add a little more detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The current `stageros` only supports one laser sensor per robot. People have long wished for a more flexible implementation, but no one has done that project yet.

It is possible to construct your own alternative to `stageros` with support for other sensors to fit your specific needs.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-09-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eisenhorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3282/eisenhorn/) on 2012-10-03**:
Does this mean, that stageros can't be extended to support more than one ultrasonic sensors?

What do you mean by alternative to stageros? Does this comprise a complete alternative from scratch?